# Does Mole 2010 support VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Mole 2010 installed in VS 2010 , but now I have loaded VS 2012 the Mole 2010 option does not appear in the Visualiser Dropdown when debugging.

Does anyone know if Mole 2010 supports VS 2012 . I have VS 2012 Ultimate installed

Comment: Do  you mean "Mole 2010", or the "Pex/Moles" technology from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

It's doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012 however the author said a new version will work in it, although he has been saying that for months. [Molosoft](http://www.molosoft.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Moles is an addon to Visual Studio and has been productized as Fakes which is available by default in VS 2012. That is the reason why you may not find Moles for 2012 on the gallery.

[See here for a comparison](http://www.richonsoftware.com/post/2012/04/20/Comparing-Microsoft-Moles-in-Visual-Studio-2010-to-Microsoft-Fakes-in-Visual-Studio-11.aspx).

Comment: Mole 2010 is a commercial product from Molosoft.